# Unwanted space : SwiftUI

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, navigationbar

How can I remove unwanted space from top and bottom in swiftUI.It's look perfect in canvas but it's showing incorrect in simulators. I'm using `Xcode 13.0 beta 3`.

> Simulator Screenshot

[image]

> Canvas Screenshot

[image]

Also Check my code. Let me correct if anything seems incorrect and cause this issue.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var arrIndex = [ModelIndex]()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(arrIndex) { val in
                Text("val")
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("List")
        }
        .onAppear{
            ClSApi.GetJsonModelValue { datas,arrInd  in
                self.arrIndex = arrInd
                print(datas)
            }
        }
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this ContentView the root view of your application?

Comment: Yes it's root view

Comment: This line `.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)` doesn't seem right on a NavigationView.

Comment: Even If remove I remove still show same extra space

Comment: Did you try putting the `.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)` on the `List()`. Barring that, it is difficult to answer your question with the information given. Please see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Are you sure you don't have double `NavigationView`s?

Comment: In most cases, this occurs when one `NavigationView` is embedded in another

Comment: Yes no double navigation for sure. @aheze

Comment: In Mac build it's showing properly.

Comment: How is the ContentView rendered? Are you using the SwiftUI App Lifecycle or old stool AppDelegate? Can you post your top level code?

Comment: did you find solution to this?